# Django multiple file upload without using AJAX & jQuery

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

Since Django doesn't allow dynamic  multiple file upload, I got to know that I have to use AJAX & jQuery to make this happen in my Content Management System for apparel images. But I being basically a backend guy, don't want to mess up with the existing working application by trying to incorporate front-end libraries in the code (I had tried this tutorial https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html but it just messes up the code).

After reading documentation several times and searching heavily, I found this on quora. http://qr.ae/TUICrh

This is just brilliant because I don't have to figure out the front-end libraries and can do the multiple upload using only Django/python code.

But I don't know how to integrate this with my code. I will attach my code here. Please help me with the code specifics.

models.py

```
def file_rename(instance, filename):
    if instance.category.name == 'Jeans':
        prefix = 'string-1'
        count = Count.objects.get(pk=1)
    elif instance.category.name == 'Kurti':
        prefix = 'string-2'
        count = Count.objects.get(pk=2)
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    ZSN = prefix + str(count.jeans_count + 1)
    filename = '{}.{}'.format(ZSN, ext)
    return os.path.join('images', filename)

class Images(models.Model):
    design_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_rename)
    cost_price = models.FloatField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    fabric = models.ForeignKey(Fabric, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    selling_price = models.FloatField()
    aliveness = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    no_of_designs_or_colors = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
    catalogue_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    visit_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    set_sizes = models.ForeignKey(Sizes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    set_cat_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    colours = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.design_id
```

forms.py

```
class ImagesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('file','category','fabric','manufacturer','cost_price','group','catalogue_name','brand', 'set_sizes','no_of_designs_or_colors','colours')
```

upload-photo.html

```
{% extends "cms/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Upload-photo
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<form id="upload_form" method="post" action="/home/upload-photo/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ upload_image.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<br />
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def uploadphoto(request):

    context_dict = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImagesForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():

            image = form.save(commit=False)


            #calculate selling price based on a percentage and store in sp
            image.selling_price = sp

            #getting all attributes and generating design-id and store in string
            image.design_id = string

            image.save()

            #putting a border to the image
            image2 = Image.open('media/' + str(image.file))
            width, height = image2.size;
            image2 = ImageOps.expand(image2, border=(int(width/25),int(height/20),int(width/25),int(height/10)), fill='rgb(0,0,0)')

            draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image2)
            font = ImageFont.truetype('Roboto-Bold.ttf', size = int(height/40))
            header = "CMS"

            #ZSN for jeans
            if cat == "Jeans":
                count = Count.objects.get(pk=1)
                count.jeans_count = count.jeans_count + 1
                count.save()
                header2 = "string-1" + str(count.jeans_count)
            else:
                count = Count.objects.get(pk=2)
                count.jeans_count = count.jeans_count + 1
                count.save()
                header2 = "string-2" + str(count.jeans_count)

            image2.save('media/' + str(image.file))
            data = open('media/' + str(image.file), 'rb')
            s3.Bucket('bucket').put_object(Key=str(image.file), Body=data)

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home/')

    else:
        form = ImagesForm()
        context_dict = {'upload_image': form}

        return render(request, 'cms/upload-photo.html',context_dict)
```

I have put the code so that you can get the flow and suggest me what changes that I have to make according to that quora link in my code to get the multiple upload ready.